# joi validation starts validating request header when I use a custom decorator

Tags: validation, nestjs, joi

I have the following code:

```
export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return request.user ?? null;
  },
);

@Injectable()
export class JoiValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private schema: ObjectSchema) {}

  transform(value: any) {
    const { error } = this.schema.validate(value);
    if (error) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Request validation failed: ' + error);
    }

    return value;
  }
}

const createPostJoiSchema = Joi.object().keys({
  content: Joi.string()
    .min(10)
    .message('Post cannot be too short.')
    .disallow(''),
  title: Joi.string().max(100).message('Max 100 characters').disallow(''),
  vote_count: Joi.number().min(1).max(1),
  tags: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().max(30).disallow('')).min(1).max(10),
});

export const createPostValidationPipe = new JoiValidationPipe(
  createPostJoiSchema,
);
@Post()
  @UseGuards(AuthGuardJwt)
  @UsePipes(createPostValidationPipe)
  async create(@Body() payload: any, @CurrentUser() currentUser) {
    console.log('post payload: ', payload);
    return;
  }
```

If I don't use the @CurrentUser() decorator, the payload prints correct, yet, using this decorator gives this error:

```
{
    "message": "Request validation failed: ValidationError: \"user_id\" is not allowed",
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "statusCode": 400
}
```

This is the implementation of the `jwtstrategy`:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(
  Strategy,
  authStrategies.jwtStrategy,
) {
  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: authConfigs.authSecret,
    });
  }

  public async validate(payload: any) {
    const userProfile = await this.userService.findOne({
      user_id: payload.sub,
    });

    return replacePasswordInNewObject(userProfile);
  }
}
```

I'm not sure, how using this decorator suddenly starts validating the user data appended in the header?

Answer (score 0):

Use joi validator in your type/DTO classes with property schemas and options

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-joi

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).